# Sorting and Grouping of Korean Character (Not familiar with Korean language)

Tags: java, sorting, localization, grouping

I'm trying to sort and group Korean character in Java.

Currently i'm about to sort by using

```
final Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.KOREA);
    Collections.sort(words, collator);
```

However, i have difficulty grouping them into their vowel group (ㄱㄴㄷㄹㅁㅂㅅㅇㅈㅊㅋㅌㅍㅎ)

Comment: Nope, there isn't anyway. The only way i can think of is the find the range of hex for each character and filter it accordingly. However, that might be very inefficient. I do not know how to read Korean language, that why i'm hoping there will be Korean developer over here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't be too difficult although I'm not sure if that's been already done before.

What you have to do is to take this first Unicode letter. In Unicode all hangul letters are composed following this formula which is nicely described at wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_language_and_computers#Example

So you can de-structure this using a formula:

```
(int)((54620 - 44032) / 588)
```

and using the key mentioned in the wikipedia article you can do something like this (I used Groovy as it's much simpler but I'm sure you can adapt it to Java)

```
def words = ['곰', '세', '마리','가', '한', '집에', '있어', '아빠', '곰', '엄마', '곰', '애기', '곰'], 
result = [('ㄱ'):[],
('ㄲ'):[],
('ㄴ'):[],
('ㄷ'):[],
('ㄸ'):[],
('ㄹ'):[],
('ㅁ'):[],
('ㅂ'):[],
('ㅃ'):[],
('ㅅ'):[],
('ㅆ'):[],
('ㅇ'):[],
('ㅈ'):[],
('ㅉ'):[],
('ㅊ'):[],
('ㅋ'):[],
('ㅌ'):[],
('ㅍ'):[],
('ㅎ'):[]], matrix = [(0):'ㄱ',
(1):'ㄲ',
(2):'ㄴ',
(3):'ㄷ',
(4):'ㄸ',
(5):'ㄹ',
(6):'ㅁ',
(7):'ㅂ',
(8):'ㅃ',
(9):'ㅅ',
(10):'ㅆ',
(11):'ㅇ',
(12):'ㅈ',
(13):'ㅉ',
(14):'ㅊ',
(15):'ㅋ',
(16):'ㅌ',
(17):'ㅍ',
(18):'ㅎ']

for (word in words) {
    def offset = (int)((word.charAt(0) - 44032) / 588)
    def firstJamo = matrix[offset]
    result[firstJamo] << word   
}

result
```

To see this code in action see https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5767123439714304.